# JQuery autocomplete plugin gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, autocomplete

my code is for getting up to response is

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/Addbus',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(data){
    var dt = JSON.parse(data.body);
        $.each(dt,function(i,v){
           $.each(v,function(j,p){
        sid.push(p.name);
            temp.push(p);
        var result=JSON.stringify(temp);
     console.log(result);

      $("#source").autocomplete({
        source: result, // The source of the AJAX results
        minLength: 3, // The minimum amount of characters that must be typed before the autocomplete is triggered
        focus: function( event, ui ) { // What happens when an autocomplete result is focused on
            $("#source").val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
      },
      select: function ( event, ui ) { // What happens when an autocomplete result is selected
          $("#source").val( ui.item.value );
          $('#source-id').val( ui.item.id );
      }
  });
```

but I'm getting error in jquery min.js.

my result which is given as source for autocomplete is as follows:

```
[{"id":"190","name":"Elurupadu"},{"id":"1230","name":"Sendhwa"},{"id":"1262","name":"Multai"},{"id":"1480","name":"Kherwara"},{"id":"2225","name":"Mandi"},{"id":"519","name":"Thamarassery"},{"id":"208","name":"Ayyampettai"},{"id":"5519","name":"Udaipur"},{"id":"26977","name":"Siddapura(Udupi)"},{"id":"1151","name":"Murthal"},{"id":"327","name":"Pillayarpatti"},{"id":"2022","name":"Siddapura"},{"id":"738","name":"Therthally"},{"id":"1112","name":"Chandigarh"},{"id":"2358","name":"Kadodra"}]
```

how to use source in autocomplete

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8081/[%7B%22id%22:%22190%22,%22name%22:%22Elurupadu%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%221230%22,%22name%22:%22Sendhwa%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%221262%22,%22name%22:%22Multai%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%221480%22,]?term=hhss net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: you should post all relevant code and errors in your question, not in comments